# Getting weird, crackly sound during voip call with slimdx

Tags: c#, udp, voip, voice, slimdx

I'm working on a VOIP application and it mostly works but I keep getting a weird crackling sound whenever someone speaks, I know it's to do with the code I have because Skype and Lync do not have these issues. Could you please let me know if there's anything I should and/or change with this code? Thanks in advance.

Initializes the objects to be used:

```
private void Initialise()
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress serverIP = IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");     // Server IP
            int port = 27005;                                           // Server port
            ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverIP, port);
            this.device = new DirectSound();
            this.device.SetCooperativeLevel(this.Handle, CooperativeLevel.Priority);

            DeviceCollection captureDeviceCollection = new DeviceCollection();
            captureDeviceCollection = DirectSoundCapture.GetDevices();
            DeviceInformation deviceInfo = captureDeviceCollection[0];
            capture = new DirectSoundCapture(deviceInfo.DriverGuid);
            short channels = 2;
            short bitsPerSample = 16;
            int samplesPerSec = 44100;

            //Set up wave format to be captured.
            wavFrmt = new WaveFormat();
            wavFrmt.Channels = channels;
            wavFrmt.FormatTag = WaveFormatTag.Pcm;
            wavFrmt.SamplesPerSecond = samplesPerSec;
            wavFrmt.BitsPerSample = bitsPerSample;
            wavFrmt.BlockAlignment = (short)(channels * (bitsPerSample / (short)8));
            wavFrmt.AverageBytesPerSecond = wavFrmt.BlockAlignment * samplesPerSec;

            capBuffDes = new CaptureBufferDescription();
            capBuffDes.BufferBytes = wavFrmt.AverageBytesPerSecond / 5;
            capBuffDes.Format = wavFrmt;

            playbackBufferDesc = new SoundBufferDescription();
            playbackBufferDesc.SizeInBytes = (wavFrmt.AverageBytesPerSecond / 5) /2;
            playbackBufferDesc.Format = wavFrmt;
            playbackBufferDesc.Flags = BufferFlags.GlobalFocus;
            playbackBuffer = new SecondarySoundBuffer(device, playbackBufferDesc);

            bufferSize = capBuffDes.BufferBytes;

            mainFrm.isCallActive = false;
            mainFrm.isSSActive = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //StopSimpleSounds();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "frmVoiceChat-Initialise()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Sends audio:

```
private void Send()
    {
        captureBuffer = new CaptureBuffer(capture, capBuffDes);
        CreateNotifyPositions();
        halfBuffer = bufferSize / 2;
        captureBuffer.Start(true);
        read1stBuffPart = true;
        offset = 0;
        mes = new byte[halfBuffer];
        try
        {
            while (!mainFrm.stop)
            {
                myWaitEventHandle.WaitOne();
                captureBuffer.Read<byte>(mes, 0, halfBuffer, offset);
                read1stBuffPart = !read1stBuffPart;
                offset = read1stBuffPart ? 0 : halfBuffer;
                udpClient.Send(mes, mes.Length, voiceCallEP);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException sockEx)
        {
            if (sockEx.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.Interrupted) { }
            else { MessageBox.Show(sockEx.Message, "Send()"); }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException){}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Send()");
        }
    }
```

Receives:

```
private void Receive()
    {
        //receiving....                
        try
        {
            while (!mainFrm.stop)
            {
                byte[] receivedData = udpClient.Receive(ref voiceCallEP);
                playbackBuffer = new SecondarySoundBuffer(device, playbackBufferDesc);
                playbackBuffer.Write(receivedData, 0, LockFlags.None);
                playbackBuffer.Play(0, PlayFlags.None);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException sockEx)
        {
            if (sockEx.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.Interrupted) { }
            else { MessageBox.Show(sockEx.Message, "Receive()"); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Receive()");
        }
    }
```

Comment: My question was unclear, I've used different methods of trying to get rid of this crackling sound such as using encoders (ALaw and Mu Law), changing the samples per second down to 8, changing the frequency between 11Khz, 22Khz and 44Khz.

And changing between 1 and 2 channels, yet none of those work. Also, I am still looking for other ways to fix this, just hope to see if I can get some help here.

Answer (score 0):

Something with your round-robin buffering seems wrong. You're intending to use half of the buffer for each call to the Read-Method, but the entire buffer length is only halfBuffer.

Try changing your code to

```
    mes = new byte[bufferSize];
    try
    {
        while (!mainFrm.stop)
        {
            myWaitEventHandle.WaitOne(); // What are you waiting on here?

            // You might need to try different arguments for the following method, the 
            // meaning from the argument 2 (startIndex) and 4 (bufferoffset) is not 
            // clear from the SlimDx documentation. 
            captureBuffer.Read<byte>(mes, offset, halfBuffer, offset);
            read1stBuffPart = !read1stBuffPart;
            udpClient.Send(mes + offset /* or equivalent */, halfBuffer, voiceCallEP);
            offset = read1stBuffPart ? 0 : halfBuffer;
        }
    }
```